# How to add a IDL Speech Recognition api to javascript

Tags: javascript, api, speech-recognition, idl, webidl

I'm new to using api's but I'd like to implement a speech recognition api in my program. I am trying to use the api at this link https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html I need to add the api into my java script how do I do so I am not familiar with WebIDL so I have no idea how to set it up.

Comment: You do not need to be familiar with WebIDL, you just need to write the code according to example: http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/. Please note that this will only work in Chrome browser.